# Why does each of query methods in ActiveRecord 'clone' a new object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In this file, https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb, most methods has following code,

```
relation = clone
```

and return `relation`. As a result, a query like this,

```
SomeModel.where(...).select(...).order(...).limit(...)
```

will clone 4 new objects.

Why don't they just use `self` and return `self`?

Comment: You may want to check out the sites mentioned here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#get-some-feedback. Someone might be able to help address your questions.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've figured out the reason. This way it ensures the flexibility.